# How can we decide if a pattern is structural

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to understand structural patterns.

Structural pattern definition:

"Structural patterns are concerned with how classes and objects are composed to
form larger structures. Structural class patterns use inheritance to compose
interfaces or implementations."

If we see that most of the design patterns we use are compositions of multiple classes, can we say that all the patterns are structural? Is there any clear differentiation between all known  structural patterns?

Answer (score 2):

"Structural patterns" is an umbrella term for design patterns used to define, well, the structure of objects, classes, and interfaces.

Composite, decorator, and adapter patterns are examples of what would be considered "structural patterns".

Here is a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) of the most popular structural patterns.